# image path is incomplete django

Tags: python, django, file, url, path

in my-projet (django)

The image path is incomplete in some api How can i fix it
like when i use this api (categories) i got this Response
Note that the image path is complete

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name_ar": "تطبيقات توصيل",
    "name_en": "weew",
    "icons": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/catecgorys/cloud123333_ZCE0xex.svg"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name_ar": "متاجر",
    "name_en": "stores",
    "icons": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/catecgorys/cloud123333_BSbQU6b.svg"
},
]
```

but when i use some api the entire image path is not displayed

like how i can fix it ?

```
{
"status": "True",
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "444",
        "percentage": "10%",
        "store": {
            "id": 1,
            "name_ar": "",
            "name_en": "noon",
            "description": "sdsdsdsdsdsdsd",
            "url": "noon.com",
            "logo": "/media/logo/Noon_log.jpeg",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name_ar": "category 1",
                    "name_en": "category 1",
                    "icons": "/media/Categories/cloud123333.svg"
                }
            ]
        },
        "description": "",
        "type": "",
        "ratings": {
            "id": 2,
            "likes": 1,
            "dislikes": 1
        }
    }
]
```

}

my code :

```
class GetCouponsByCategoryAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
queryset = Coupons.objects.all()
serializer_class = CouponsSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    categorys_id = request.data.get("Categories_id")
    if not categorys_id:
        return Response({"error": "Categories_id parameter is required."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    try:
        category = Categories.objects.get(id=categorys_id)
        stores = Stores.objects.filter(catecgorys=category)
    except Categories.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({"status": "False", "error": "Category not found."}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    except Stores.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({"status": "False", "error": "Store not found."}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    coupons = Coupons.objects.filter(store__in=stores)
    serializer = CouponsSerializer(coupons, many=True)
    return Response({"status": "True", "data": serializer.data})
```